# FOR XML AUTO and sql server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005

```
SELECT  * FROM emp FOR XML AUTO , ROOT ('Employees') , ELEMENTS
```

this query return value in xml format but total xml is showing in one column and column name is showing dynamically. if i want that i will specify the column name like data etc. so xml value will show as single row & column but header or output column name will be "DATA"

is it possible if yes the please show me the way.thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check out the new `FOR XML PATH` feature in SQL Server 2005 and up - read all about it in [SQL Server Books Online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189885.aspx).

Basically, with `FOR XML PATH`, you can define the shape of your XML very easily, e.g.

```
SELECT
    EmployeeID AS '@EmployeeID',
    FirstName,
    LastName
FROM dbo.Employees
FOR XML PATH('Employee'), ROOT('AllEmployees')
```

will generate XML something like:

```
<AllEmployees>
   <Employee EmployeeID="12345">
      <FirstName>John</FirstName>
      <LastName>Doe</LastName>
   </Employee>
</AllEmployees>
```

`FOR XML PATH` is very flexible and allows you to do a lot of things quite easily and intuitively.

Comment: check when u execute the sql with for xml path in sql management studio it still return column name dynamically.it is not working boss.

Comment: @Thomas: I'm not clear what you mean by "column name is showing dynamically"..... ?????